# How to make a shell script that connects to a server and executes commands inside `screens`?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, screen

On Linux. I need to write a file containing a script.
My script should connect to a server, create a `screen` and execute a command. Several times automatically.

Pseudocode of the script:

```
ssh machine1
cd project_folder
screen -S screenA
python run.py -x
exit
screen -S screenB
python run.py -y
exit
exit

ssh machine2
cd project_folder
screen -S screenA
python run.py -z
exit
screen -S screenB
python run.py -t
exit
exit
```

ATM I can just connect and run each command manually.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/9215267/siddharth-dushantha
And for the part of `screen` the code is

```
screen -dmS screen0
screen -ls
screen -r screen0 -p 0 -X stuff "the_command1^M"
screen -r screen0 -p 0 -X stuff "the_command2^M"
```

where `^M` types `enter` at the end of the line.